# Use for loop in VHDL

Tags: for-loop, vhdl

I am new to VHDL and quite unfamiliar with the syntax.
I am instantiating a 2-bit full-adder in 32 bit adder and I want to know how I can use a "for loop" instead of repeating the port maps in the following piece of code:

```
architecture Adder_4bit_Impl of adder_4bit is
    component fullAdder is
        Port (
            a   :in std_logic;
            b   :in std_logic;
            cin :in std_logic;
            sum :out std_logic;
            cout:out std_logic
            );
    end component;
    signal wire: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
    p1: fullAdder port map(a_in(0), b_in(0), c_in, result(0), wire(0));
    p2: fullAdder port map(a_in(1), b_in(1), wire(0), result(1), wire(1));
    p3: fullAdder port map(a_in(2), b_in(2), wire(1), result(2), wire(2));
    p4: fullAdder port map(a_in(3), b_in(3), wire(2), result(3), c_out);
end Adder_8bit_Impl;
```

Comment: It's called a for generate statement a subclass of generate statement (a concurrent statement while a loop statement with a for iteration scheme is a sequential statement).  Provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your adder without the generate statement. You can also try to implement it your self. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11. 8 Generate statements.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194450/is-it-possible-to-create-several-instances-of-the-same-component-using-a-loop/13194608#13194608

Comment: And here: https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_ease/ (see section "Extensions to generate".)

Comment: You don't actually need any of the new -2008 features for generate statements in this instance. It can be done with a single for generate statement. Note the architecture name doesn't match in the architecture body end statement. `architecture Adder_4bit_Impl of adder_4bit is` versus `end Adder_8bit_Impl;` IEEE Std 1076-2008 3.3 Architecture bodies, 3.3.1 *If a simple name appears at the end of an architecture body, it shall repeat the identifier of the architecture body.*

Comment: @user1155120 true. Just wanted to provide a link to more information.